# Pie Or Donut chart click listener

Tags: android, scichart

How to attach a click listener/ GestureListener to a pie/donut chart in the Android app using sci chart (When a slice is clicked)? I couldn't such a similar method in sci chart

This is how it's done with MPChart.

```
mChart.setOnChartGestureListener(new OnChartGestureListener() {

        @Override
        public void onChartTranslate(MotionEvent me, float dX, float dY) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onChartSingleTapped(MotionEvent me) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }

        @Override
        public void onChartScale(MotionEvent me, float scaleX, float scaleY) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onChartLongPressed(MotionEvent me) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onChartFling(MotionEvent me1, MotionEvent me2,
                float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onChartDoubleTapped(MotionEvent me) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Thanks for reading. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get notifications when slice becomes selected/unselected just add listener for PieSegment by calling [addIsSelectedChangeListener()](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/android/current/webframe.html#SciChart.Charting~com.scichart.charting.visuals.renderableSeries.IPieSegment~addIsSelectedChangeListener.html)

```
    final PieSegment pieSegment = sciChartBuilder.newPieSegment().build();
    pieSegment.addIsSelectedChangeListener(new PieSegmentChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPieSegmentChanged(IPieSegment segment) {
            //do something here
        }
    });
```